# Testing an Angular Service with Karma not working properly

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, karma-runner

My test is:

```
'use strict';
(function() {
  describe('Service: Summary', function () {
    var $httpBackend;
    // load the service's module
    beforeEach(module('mean'));

    var SummaryService;

    beforeEach(inject(function($injector, _SummaryService_) {
      SummaryService = _SummaryService_;
      $httpBackend = $injector.get('$httpBackend');      
    }));

    // instantiate service
    it('should do something', function () {
      expect(!!SummaryService).toBe(true);
    });

    it('should get a summary', function () {
      $httpBackend.expectGET('/api/ABC').respond(200);
      SummaryService.get();
    });
  });
})();
```

My service is:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('mean')
.service('SummaryService', ['$http', function SummaryService($http) {
  var summary = this;

  summary.get = function () {
    return $http.get('/api/summary');
  };
}]);
```

As you can see, it should go to `/api/summary` instead of `/api/ABC`, but the test still passes. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend that you add the following code to your test:

```
afterEach(function() {
     $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation();
     $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingRequest();
});
```

The first one will ensure that all expectations that you have defined will be made. In your case `$httpBackend.expectGET('/api/ABC')` is an outstanding request that is never made.

The second one will ensure that there are no more request that have not been flushed. In your case `$http.get('/api/summary')` is never flushed.

In fact in your tests you did not test the requests. A usual test case would do the following:

1. define the expectation
2. check the preconditions of your backend call
3. run the code that will execute the backend call
4. flush the httpBackend ($httpBackend.flush()) e.g. the backend call will full filled
5. check the post conditions

You may change the order of #2 and #3 because the backend call will not happen before `$httpBackend.flush()` is called.

See [$httpBackend](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock.%24httpBackend) for more information.